# Python spit by multiple conditions

Tags: python

Re-iterating

I have string below. I need to split this into 3 columns - tier1 ,tier2 and tier 3

Example:

```
string = "ABC(DEF,GH(123,222));IJK(LM,OP);QR;ST;UV(XY(45,56))"
```

The string should be split by ";" and "(" and ","

I am getting the result below

```
 TIER1   TIER2  TIER3
  ABC     DEF
  ABC     GH
  IJK     LM
  IJK     OP
  QR       
  ST       
  UV      XY
```

I need like below

```
 TIER1   TIER2  TIER3
  ABC     DEF   
  ABC     GH     123
  ABC     GH     222
  IJK     LM
  IJK     OP
  QR      
  ST       
  UV      XY    45
  UV      XY    56
```

Pasting the working code below but i am not getting the desired output for tier3 .

```
string="ABC(DEF,GH(123));IJK(LM,OP);QR;ST;UV(XY(45,56))"
s=string.split(";")
tier1 = [];tier2 = [];tier3=[]
for x in s:
  print("x",x)
  x = x.split('(')
  tier1.append(x[0])
  print(x)
  try:
      r = x[1].replace(')', '')
      a=r.split(',')
      for i in range(0,len(a)):
          if i == 0:
              tier2.append(a[i])
          else:
              tier1.append(x[0])
              tier2.append(a[i])
              
  except:
    tier2.append('')
    
print('TIER 1' + '\t ' + 'TIER 2')
for i in range(len(tier1)):
    print(tier1[i] + '\t ' + tier2[i] )
```

Comment: Do you need to print like this? or need A list of Tier1 and tier2?

Comment: Please rewrite your question without using CAPS

Comment: Could you explain where the line `BB  CC` comes from in the output?

Comment: @Vignesh Rajendran: i have re-iterated the question

Answer (score 2):

Implementation without re and Print statement as you expected,

```
s = "ABC(DEF);EFG(HI);JK;LM;OP(QR)"
s = s.split(';')
tier1 = [];tier2 = []
for x in s:
  x = x.split('(')
  tier1.append(x[0])
  try:
    s = x[1].replace(')', '')
    tier2.append(s)
  except:
    tier2.append('')
print('TIER 1' + '\t ' + 'TIER 2')
for i in range(len(tier1)):
    print(tier1[i] + '\t ' + tier2[i])
```

Output:

```
TIER 1   TIER 2
ABC      DEF
EFG      HI
JK   
LM   
OP       QR
```

Comment: I have re-iterated the question - Please check

Answer (score 1):

This will work, comment with any questions

```
string = "ABC(DEF);EFG(HI);JK;LM;OP(QR)"

print("TIER1 TIER2")
for s in string.split(";"):
    if "(" in s:
        a,b = s.split("(")
        if b.endswith(")"): b = b.strip(")")
        print(a.ljust(5),b)
    else:
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for reiteration:

```
import itertools

string = "ABC(DEF,GH(123,222));IJK(LM,OP);QR;ST;UV(XY(45,56))"
c=[]
tier1, tier2, tier3 = [], [], []

s=string.split(";")
for v in s:
  x,y,z = [],[''],['']
  d = v.split('(')
  x = d[0].split(',')
  if len(d) == 2:
    y = d[1].replace(')', '')
    y=y.split(',')
  elif len(d) == 3:
    y = d[1].replace(')', '').split(',')
    z = d[2].replace(')', '').split(',')  

  c.extend(list(itertools.product(x, y, z)))

for i in c:
  tier1.append(i[0])
  tier2.append(i[1])
  tier3.append(i[2])

print('TIER 1' + '\t ' + 'TIER 2' + '\t ' + 'TIER 3')
for i in range(len(tier1)):
    print(tier1[i] + '\t ' + tier2[i] + '\t' + tier3[i])
```

Output:

```
T1   T2  T3
ABC  DEF 123
ABC  DEF 222
ABC  GH  123
ABC  GH  222
IJK  LM 
IJK  OP 
QR      
ST      
UV   XY  45
UV   XY  56
```